# Como puedo seleccionar una casilla con el mouse y asignarla a una variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Soy nuevo con VBA, la idea que tengo es seleccionar una celda de excel (la cual tiene un correo) con el mouse y gracias a la función Offset llenar los demás campos. Este es el código que llevo actualmente.

```
Sub enviarcorreo()
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim pagina1 As Worksheet
Set pagina1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Ejemplo1")
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim Correo As Object
Dim cell As Range


With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With
'Comprobar si Outlook esta abierto y en caso de no estarlo abrirlo
On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject("", "Outlook.Application")
Err.Clear
If OutApp Is Nothing Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Visible = True
Set Correo = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


        email_ = cell.Value
       'subject_ = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        body_ = cell.Offset(0, 11).Value
        body1_ = cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        cc_ = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        attach_ = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        destinatario_ = cell.Offset(0, 16).Value
        memofolio_ = cell.Offset(0, 17).Value
        Nmemofolio_ = cell.Offset(0, 18).Value
        Fechamemofolio_ = cell.Offset(0, 19).Value

'Crear el correo y mostrarlo
With Correo
    .To = email_
    .CC = cc_
    .Subject = "Estado del Proyecto"
    .Body = "Infomo a usted que la iniciativa con nombre: " & body1_ & " fue enviada a " & destinatario_ & " via " & memofolio_ & " N°" & Nmemofolio_ & " con fecha " & Fechamemofolio_ & " para su revisión. Saluda Atentamente a usted, Unidad de Preinversión División de Planificación y Desarrollo"
    .Display
End With
With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Todo el código lo he creado gracias a muchos sitios web y tutoriales. La idea no es hacer un "for", solo necesito seleccionar un solo correo y gracias al correo seleccionado, darle toda la otra información. Estaría muy agradecido si me echan una mano con esto. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe un comando en VBA para hacer referencia a la celda seleccionada activamente. Se lllama `ActiveCell`.

Por ejemplo, si tienes seleccionada la celda B8, y dentro tiene un e-mail tipo `nombre@hotmail.com`, si usas `email_ = ActiveCell.Value` guardarás dentro de la variable `email` el valor de la celda B8.

Así que reemplaza todos tus `Cell` por `ActiveCell`, y nos cuentas.

Más información:

> [Propiedad Application.ActiveCell
>   (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell)